# Error while downloading to memory using curl

Tags: c++, curl, memory

I want to download a file to memory using curl.
I am currently using [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) and it looks like it works to a certain extent but corrupts my file.
I have used sigbench and it is around 20% different (while comparing original and downloaded)
[image]

The file I want to download is a binary so it won't work after it's modified.
I am currently testing with the x86 version of [this](https://github.com/carterjones/hello-world-dll).
[original binary](https://cdn.otaku.ooo/8au89.dll)
[downloaded binary](https://cdn.otaku.ooo/nfee3.dll)
This is the code I am using to write it to a file:
`ofstream stream = ofstream("test.dll");
stream.write(chunk.memory, chunk.size);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opening the file like this:

```
ofstream stream = ofstream("test.dll");
```

will cause line-end characters to be adjusted to match your target system.

You should instead open the file in binary mode:

```
ofstream stream = ofstream("test.dll", std::ios::binary);
```

This will leave the characters that could be interpreted as line-endings unchanged.

Further reading: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c#Binary_and_text_modes

Comment: You don't need to use `ofstream stream = ofstream(...);`, just use `ofstream stream (...);` instead. Also, don't forget to include the `std::ios::app` or `std::ios::ate` flag if you want to **append** to an existing file, otherwise the file will be wiped each time it is opened.